# How to add a custom field into the ARInvoice Customer selector?

Tags: customization, selector, acumatica

There is a custom field, that I declared for the Customer DAC:

```
public class CustomerExt : PXCacheExtension<Customer>
{
    #region UsrDemoField
    [PXDBString(255)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Demo Field")]

    public virtual string UsrDemoField { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrDemoField : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```

Attempts to modify the ARInvoice Customer selector with the Customize Selector Columns popup didn't seem to work. How can I add my custom field into the ARInvoice customer selector?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Be aware, since Acumatica ERP build #17.201.0043**, it's possible to customize the list of columns defined for AR Invoices' **Customer** lookup via the **Customize Selector Columns** dialog (available in the Data Class section of the Customization Manager). For step-by-step instructions please check the screenshot below:
[image]

**To modify AR Invoices' Customer lookup on Acumatica ERP ver. 6.1 and earlier, please follow the steps below:**
The definition of PXCustomizeSelectorColumns generated by the Customize Selector Columns popup brilliantly works with the majority of selectors inside Acumatica ERP. Basically, PXCustomizeSelectorColumns simply replaces originally defined columns for a selector with the custom set of columns during an initialization of PXCache:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PXCustomizeSelectorColumns: PXEventSubscriberAttribute
{
    private readonly Type[] _columns;

    public PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(params Type[] columns)
    {
        _columns = columns;
    }

    public override void CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {
        cache.SetAltered(this.FieldName, true);
        foreach (PXEventSubscriberAttribute attr in cache.GetAttributes(null, this.FieldName))
        {
            PXSelectorAttribute sel = attr as PXSelectorAttribute;
            if (sel == null) 
                continue;
            sel.SetFieldList(_columns);
            sel.Headers = null;
        }
    }
}
```

***So what can cause the PXCustomizeSelectorColumns attribute to fail and not replace selector's originally defined columns?*** Any time the `SetColumns` method is executed on an instance of PXDimensionSelectorAttribute or PXSelectorAttribute after PXCache was initialized, there is no chance for PXCustomizeSelectorColumns to do its job.

```
[PXDBInt()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[Serializable]
public class CustomerAttribute : AcctSubAttribute
{
    ...
    public virtual void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.AttributeLevel == PXAttributeLevel.Item || e.IsAltered)
        {
            PopulateFields(sender);
        }

        PXFieldSelecting handler = GetAttribute<PXDimensionSelectorAttribute>().FieldSelecting;
        handler(sender, e);
    }

    protected virtual void PopulateFields(PXCache sender)
    {
        if (_FieldList == null)
        {
            _FieldList = new string[this._fields.Length];
            _HeaderList = new string[this._fields.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < this._fields.Length; i++)
            {
                Type cacheType = BqlCommand.GetItemType(_fields[i]);
                PXCache cache = sender.Graph.Caches[cacheType];
                if (cacheType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(BAccountR)) ||
                    _fields[i].Name == typeof(BAccountR.acctCD).Name ||
                    _fields[i].Name == typeof(BAccountR.acctName).Name)
                {
                    _FieldList[i] = _fields[i].Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    _FieldList[i] = cacheType.Name + "__" + _fields[i].Name;
                }
                _HeaderList[i] = PXUIFieldAttribute.GetDisplayName(cache, _fields[i].Name);
            }
        }

        var attr = GetAttribute<PXDimensionSelectorAttribute>().GetAttribute<PXSelectorAttribute>();
        attr.SetColumns(_FieldList, _HeaderList);
    }
    ...
}
```

With that said, to add a custom field into the ARInvoice Customer selector, one should replace all attributes declared for the ARInvoice.CustomerID field and redefine columns for the Customer selector within the CustomerActive attribute:
[image]

```
[PXDefault()]
[CustomerActive(typeof(Search<BAccountR.bAccountID>),
    new Type[]
    {
        typeof(BAccountR.acctCD),
        typeof(BAccountR.acctName),
        typeof(CustomerExt.usrDemoField),
        typeof(Address.addressLine1),
        typeof(Address.addressLine2),
        typeof(Address.postalCode),
        typeof(CustomerAttribute.Contact.phone1),
        typeof(Address.city),
        typeof(Address.countryID),
        typeof(CustomerAttribute.Location.taxRegistrationID),
        typeof(Customer.curyID),
        typeof(CustomerAttribute.Contact.salutation),
        typeof(Customer.customerClassID),
        typeof(Customer.status)
    },
    Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DescriptionField = typeof(Customer.acctName), Filterable = true, TabOrder = 2)]
```

After publishing the customization, custom Demo Field should finally appear in the ARInvoice Customer selector:
[image]

To enable searching against a custom field inside the ARInvoice Customer selector, open Invoices and Memos screen in the Layout Editor and type ***UsrDemoField*** as the GridProperties.FastFilterFields property of the Customer selector:

[image]

[image]