# PXCustomizeSelectorColumns messes up column names

Tags: acumatica

I'm using the following code to add postal code to the BA selector on the Case screen.

It works and adds the new column, but it messes up the column names.  See the screenshot below the code.

How can I get around this?  Is there a way to pass the column headers in the PXCustomizeSelectorColumns attribute?

```
      [PXNonInstantiatedExtension]
  public class CR_CRCase_ExistingColumn : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.CRCase>
  {
      #region CustomerID  
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]

[PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.acctCD),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.acctName),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.type),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.BAccount.classID),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.status),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Contact.phone1),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Address.city),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Address.countryID),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Contact.eMail),
typeof(PX.Objects.CR.Address.postalCode))]
      public int? CustomerID { get; set; }
      #endregion
  }
```

[image: Text]

```
[CustomerAndProspect(DisplayName = "Business Account")]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Current<CRCaseClass.requireCustomer>, Equal<False>,
  Or<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>,
Or<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.combinedType>>>>), Messages.CustomerRequired, typeof(BAccount.acctCD))]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        [PXFormula(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<CRCase.caseClassID, IsNotNull, And<Selector<CRCase.caseClassID, CRCaseClass.requireCustomer>, Equal<True>,
                                         And<Current<CRCase.customerID>, IsNotNull, And<Selector<Current<CRCase.customerID>, BAccount.type>, Equal<BAccountType.prospectType>>>>>,
                                         Null>,
                             CRCase.customerID>))]
[PXFormula(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<Current<CRCase.customerID>, IsNull, And<Current<CRCase.contractID>, IsNotNull>>, 
IsNull<Selector<CRCase.contractID, Selector<ContractBillingSchedule.accountID, BAccount.acctCD>>,
 Selector<CRCase.contractID, Selector<Contract.customerID, BAccount.acctCD>>>>, 
 CRCase.customerID>))]
[PXFormula(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<Current<CRCase.customerID>, IsNull, 
 And<Current<CRCase.contactID>, IsNotNull, 
 And<Selector<CRCase.contactID, Contact.bAccountID>, IsNotNull>>>, 
Selector<CRCase.contactID, Selector<Contact.bAccountID, BAccount.acctCD>>>, 
CRCase.customerID>))]
```

Here's my current code.  It pulls the zip code in, but it now shows all BAccounts not just customers and prospects. The code does not give any errors when checking it in Acuminator.

```
  [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
  [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXDimensionSelectorAttribute))]
  [PXDimensionSelector(BAccountAttribute.DimensionName,
  typeof(Search2<
    BAccountR.bAccountID,
  LeftJoin<Contact,
    On<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>,
    And<Contact.contactID, Equal<BAccountR.defContactID>>>,
  LeftJoin<Address,
    On<Address.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>,
    And<Address.addressID, Equal<BAccountR.defAddressID>>>>>,
  Where<
    Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>,
    And<Where<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.prospectType>,
    Or<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>,
    Or<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.combinedType>>>>>
    >>),
  substituteKey: typeof(BAccountR.acctCD),
  fieldList: new[]
  {
typeof(BAccountR.acctCD),
typeof(BAccountR.acctName),
typeof(BAccountR.type),
typeof(BAccountR.classID),
typeof(BAccountR.status),
typeof(Contact.phone1),
typeof(Address.city),
typeof(Address.postalCode),
typeof(Address.countryID),
typeof(Contact.eMail)
  }
  )]
  protected virtual void CRCase_CustomerID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{

}
```

I'm getting these errors on compile:

\App_RuntimeCode\CRCaseMaint.cs(84): error CS0311: The type 'PX.Data.Match<PX.Data.Current<PX.Data.AccessInfo.userName>>' cannot be used as type parameter 'Operand' in the generic type or method 'Where<Operand, Comparison>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PX.Data.Match<PX.Data.Current<PX.Data.AccessInfo.userName>>' to 'PX.Data.IBqlOperand'.
\App_RuntimeCode\CRCaseMaint.cs(85): error CS0311: The type 'PX.Data.And<PX.Data.Where<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.type, PX.Data.Equal<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountType.prospectType>, PX.Data.Or<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.type, PX.Data.Equal<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountType.customerType>, PX.Data.Or<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.type, PX.Data.Equal<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountType.combinedType>>>>>' cannot be used as type parameter 'Comparison' in the generic type or method 'Where<Operand, Comparison>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PX.Data.And<PX.Data.Where<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.type, PX.Data.Equal<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountType.prospectType>, PX.Data.Or<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.type, PX.Data.Equal<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountType.customerType>, PX.Data.Or<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountR.type, PX.Data.Equal<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountType.combinedType>>>>>' to 'PX.Data.IBqlComparison'.
\App_RuntimeCode\CRCaseMaint.cs(84): error CS0311: The type 'PX.Data.Match<PX.Data.Current<PX.Data.AccessInfo.userName>>' cannot be used as type parameter 'Operand' in the generic type or method 'Where<Operand, Comparison>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PX.Data.Match<PX.Data.Current<PX.Data.AccessInfo.userName>>' to 'PX.Data.IBqlOperand'.

I also tried copying the PXRestrictor attribute from the CustomerAndProspectAttribute, but it seemed to ignore it.

#region CustomerAndProspectAttribute

```
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.prospectType>,
        Or<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>,
        Or<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.combinedType>>>>), Messages.BAccountIsType, typeof(BAccountR.type))]
```

Comment: have you looked into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45043822/how-to-add-a-custom-field-into-the-arinvoice-customer-selector/45043824#45043824  ?

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the link.  I had seen this post, and that's the method I used to generate the code above.  The only difference was, that I had an existing dac extension code file already for this DAC, so I used a separate customization project to generate the code and then copied it to my existing extension in my other customization project.     Would that explain why the columns header are showing as they are in my screen shot?

Comment: as explained in the link. PXCustomizeSelectorColumns do not work well with PXDimensionSelector. You need to redeclare your BA selector with your own lookup columns.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I see what you are saying now.  I'm still a bit confused on how to apply this to the business account selector on the case screen.  I edited the post to add the original attributes for the field.  Do I need to define the columns in the CustomerAndProspect attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I just overridden the dimension selector this way:

```
public class OpportunityMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<OpportunityMaint>
{
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
    [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXDimensionSelectorAttribute))]
    [PXDimensionSelector(BAccountAttribute.DimensionName,
    typeof(Search2<
      BAccountR.bAccountID,
    LeftJoin<Contact,
      On<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>,
      And<Contact.contactID, Equal<BAccountR.defContactID>>>,
    LeftJoin<Address,
      On<Address.bAccountID, Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>,
      And<Address.addressID, Equal<BAccountR.defAddressID>>>>>,
    Where<
      Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>),
    substituteKey: typeof(BAccountR.acctCD),
    fieldList: new[]
    {
      typeof(BAccountR.acctCD),
      typeof(BAccountR.acctName),
      typeof(BAccountR.type),
      typeof(BAccountR.classID),
      typeof(BAccountR.status),
      typeof(Contact.phone1),
      typeof(Address.city),
      typeof(Address.postalCode),
      typeof(Address.countryID),
      typeof(Contact.eMail)
    }
    )]
    protected virtual void CROpportunity_BAccountID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }      
}
```

Managed to expose the postal code :

[image]

Not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing it. But it ticks the box.

Comment: Hi @Rick, thanks for this.  It's working, but I do have an issue.  It's showing all business accounts not just customer and prospects.  I tried adding to the where clause but I'm getting an error when compiling.  I will update my post with my current code and the compile error